# companion objects for type alias

Tags: scala

I have the following case class with a companion object:

```
case class A(boo:String)
object A{
 def foo(x:a) = ...
}
```

And I have the following type alias in my package object:

```
type NewA = A
```

I want all the method in A companion object to be in the companion object of NewA. I know one way to do it but it's not nice:

```
object NewA{
  val instance = A
}
NewA.instance.foo(...)
```

is there any way to write it in a better way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply add a `val` to your package object that references `A`:

```
package object your_package {
  type NewA = A
  val NewA = A
}
```

Then you can use `NewA` from `your_package` just like you would use `A`:

```
import your_package.NewA

NewA.foo(...)
```

Comment: It works in most contexts but there is no implicit scope in val NewA

Answer (score 0):

You could use implicit conversions to convert `NewA` into `A`

```scala
implicit convertNewA2A(newA: NewA.type) = A

NewA.foo(...)
```

Alternatively, you could factor the methods of `A` out into a trait from which both companion objects extend.